# Onselectedindexchanged is firing

Tags: asp.net

In grid row command event I am calling a `.ascx` page as a popup.

In the popup I have one button, on clicking the button, I'm calling one more popup.

Under the second popup I have four dropdown controls, in the dropdown controls I'm filtering and filling the data one after another.

The problem here is, if I filter the third dropdown, the second dropdown field data is getting reset(Onselectedindexchanged is firing).

Comment: Anyone good at riddles?;) @Akshata: would you reformat it?

Comment: Check the IsPostBack on the page load, usually this creates such problems.

Comment: We have two popups it is loaded by using modular popup extender .In the second popup we have four dropdownlist controls and a button,2nd dropdownlist  is loaded on the selection of first dropdownlist  (on selected index change event), similarly fourth dropdown is also loaded onselection of third , on click of button selected index of both the dropdowns (i.e. second and fourth dropdownlist) are reset to default values , could you suggest how to handle this scenario

Comment: IsPostBack is always true on loading secound popup.

Answer (score 0):

You might be reloading/binding the drop downs on post back. You may want to change it to something like this

if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
//load the dropdowns the first time.
}